# Queuing in JavaScript - how to call the next function

Tags: javascript, function, events, queue

I want to write a queue that I can use over and over in my application.  I know that queues exist but I:

a) want to try this myself

b) want to have full control over the code

c) don't want a library for what I think is a seemingly simple task.

So far I have an array that holds my functions to be processed, and I use shift() and push() to manage the array contents.

This is working great EXCEPT that I don't want my queue to automatically process the next function all the time.  Because this queue can be used for a variety of processes where order is important in execution, I need a way to only process the next function when the first has finished.  The catch is I don't know what defines "finished".  An example I have been using for myself is lets say a user uploads 5 photos to my application, before the next image can be uploaded the user needs to click a button to "OK" the image preview.  I also want to use this same queue for when I want to automatically process the next function.

So far I have the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/21bc4ezu/

```
var q = [],
     processing;

function runNextFunction() {

    while (q.length) {

      if(!processing){
        processing = true;
        q.shift()();
      }

      processing = false;
    }
};

  function fillQueue(func) {
    q.push(func);
    runNextFunction();
  };
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that is a seemingly simple task. It can become really complex depending on what you want to achieve. Anyways, I think you are looking for something similar to a Promise system, aren't you? Somehow to control the life state of a process, so that you can synchronize execution, am I right?